# SQL Server :Counting time between Date Values

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, sum

If i have a table which has a data column, how can i count the time period in hours between the entries.
Assuming that 1 row effectively signifies the state change of the previous row.
eg

```
TableA
Name Status(Int) DateTime (DateTiem2)
Bob In '2012-11-22 00:00:00'
Bob Out '2012-11-23 00:00:00'
Bob In '2012-11-24 00:00:00'
Bob Out '2012-11-25 00:00:00'
Bob In '2012-11-26 00:00:00'
Bob Out '2012-11-26 12:30:00'
Bob Absent '2012-11-27 00:00:00'
Bob In '2012-11-27 01:00:00
Jo In '2012-11-22 00:00:00'
Jo Out '2012-11-23 00:00:00'
Jo In '2012-11-24 00:00:00'
Jo Out '2012-11-25 00:00:00'
Jo In '2012-11-26 00:00:00'
Jo Out '2012-11-26 12:30:00'
Jo Absent '2012-11-27 00:00:00'
Jo In '2012-11-27 01:00:00
```

Totals Query result from
Bob In: 60.5 hrs
Bob Out: 59.5 hrs
Bob Absent: 1 hr
Jo In: 60.5 hrs
Jo Out: 59.5 hrs
Jo Absent: 1 hr

Comment: Is the order of the rows supplied by the `DateTime` column? Otherwise _previous row_ doesn't mean much.

Comment: Tip: You may want to consider naming entities using something other than keywords. `SELECT [DELETE] FROM [WHERE] WHERE [FROM] < [INSERT] ORDER BY [INT]` might be confusing to someone.

Comment: Thanks - this is of course an example table, my entities are named appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself so each row matches the next one in sequence.  Then subtract date time amounts by minute (since you want fractional hours) and divide the minutes by 60:

```
declare @T table
(
    name varchar(20),
    [status] int,
    [DateTime] datetime2
)

insert into @T (name, [status], [DateTime])
values ('Bob', 0, '2012-11-22 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 1, '2012-11-23 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 0, '2012-11-24 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 1, '2012-11-25 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 0, '2012-11-26 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 1, '2012-11-26 12:30:00'),
('Bob', 2, '2012-11-27 00:00:00'),
('Bob', 1, '2012-11-27 01:00:00'),
('Jo', 0, '2012-11-22 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 1, '2012-11-23 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 0, '2012-11-24 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 1, '2012-11-25 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 0, '2012-11-26 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 1, '2012-11-26 12:30:00'),
('Jo', 2, '2012-11-27 00:00:00'),
('Jo', 1, '2012-11-27 01:00:00')

;with RowNumbers (RowNum, name, [status], [DateTime])
as
(
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by name order by [DateTime]),
        name,
        [status],
        [DateTime]
    from @T
)
select
    T1.name,
    case T1.[status]
        when 0 then 'In'
        when 1 then 'Out'
        when 2 then 'Absent'
      end as [status],
    sum(datediff(MINUTE, T1.[DateTime], T2.[DateTime]) / 60.0) as [hours]
from RowNumbers T1
    inner join RowNumbers T2
        on T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum - 1 -- joins the current row to the next one
        and T1.name = T2.name
group by T1.name, T1.[status]
order by T1.Name, T1.[status]
```

Note that the above query is probably not going to perform as well as a derived table that has an index on the row number.

Also, the query I made some assumptions about the data types and actual values of the name and status column.  The general approach remains the same.

Comment: Fantastic - this worked. Now i mistakenly forgot to include an important detail - can i do this grouped by a third column? I have edited my original question  - is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  You will need to pass the name around and add it to the group by clause.  I will update the query.

Comment: Actually, problemo! The above works as long as the names are all grouped in th etable originally but in my table they ae not. They are Jo, Bob, Jo, Jo, Bob etc and i find that the count is no longer working. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm getting the original correct results even with entries out of order.  You could try changing `partition by name order by [DateTime]` to `partition by name order by name, [DateTime]`.  Otherwise, I think you'll have to post more information.